# How to run a cron jobs in every minute for a specific hour on server

Tags: php, cron

Here I am trying to run a php file through cron job process. I want to run that php file For every minute from 4PM to 5PM. I have tried both

```
*   16-17   *   *   *
```

And

```
*   16,17   *   *   *
```

But It's not working. How should I write the exact command to run this?

Comment: Just google for "cronjob generator". There are tools for that.

Comment: Try `* 16,17 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Have a look at [Crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/#*_16-17_*_*_*)

Comment: You mention it is not working, what is not working? Please specify.

Comment: Also, have a look at this: https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include multiple specific values in a cron job you separate them with commas.

For 16-17 you want `16,17` so you get:

```
# m |  h  | d | m | Day of week
  *  16,17  *   *   *

# All the below can include multiple values using commas
# m = minute (minute from 0 to 59)
# h = hour (hour of the day, from 0 to 23)
# d = day (day of month, from 1 to 31)
# m = month (month of the year, where 1 is January)
# dow = day of the week (0-7 where 0 and 7 are Sunday)
```